# Question about the intensity of a cox process, Diggle–Moraga–Rowlingson–Taylor (2013)

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, expectation

On page 2 of *"Spatial and spatio-temporal log-Gaussian Cox processes: Extending the geostatistical paradigm"* by Diggle–Moraga–Rowlingson–Taylor (2013), accessible at [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6536), they claim the following on the bottom right of the page:

> "...in the stationary case the intensity of the Cox process is equal to the expectation of Λ(x)"

My assumption is that by "intensity", they are referring to some extension of $$ \lambda (t)=\lim _{h\downarrow 0}{\frac {1}{h}}\mathbb {E} [N(t+h)-N(t)|{\mathcal {F}}_{t}],$$ as taken from wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_of_counting_processes.

I mentioned "extension" because in the Diggle–Moraga–Rowlingson–Taylor paper, they define the Cox process on $\mathbb {R}^2$, whereas the intensity definition from Wikipedia is to do with processes defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

My issue is that I'm unable to find a proof of their claim. If someone more experienced in this field could explain to me why the authors' claim is true / guide me to a relevant source, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [intensity function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntensityFunction.html) of a [point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process#Definition) $(N_B)$ over $\mathbb R^d$ is defined as the density of the intensity measure $\mu$ of $(N_B)$ relative to the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R^d$ (in your case, the Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R^2$).

In turn, the [intensity measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntensityMeasure.html) $\mu$ of $(N_B)$ is defined by the formula $\mu(B):=EN_B$ for all Borel sets $B$, in your case all Borel subsets $B$ of $\mathbb R^2$.

---

Now, conditionally on a nonnegative-valued process $\Lambda=(\Lambda_x)_{x\in\mathbb R^2}$, the Cox process $(N_B)$ over $\mathbb R^2$ is an inhomogeneous Poisson process with intensity $(\Lambda_x)$. So, for all Borel subsets $B$ of $\mathbb R^2$
$$E(N_B|\Lambda)=\int_B\Lambda_x\,dx,$$
whence
$$EN_B=EE(N_B|\Lambda)=E\int_B \Lambda_x\,dx=\int_B E\Lambda_x\,dx.$$
Thus, $(E\Lambda_x)_{x\in\mathbb R^2}$ is indeed the intensity function of the Cox process; the stationarity assumption is not needed here.

Comment: Thanks, I think this makes sense to me (wish I could upvote but I lack the reputation at the moment haha). 

Just a question, I notice that the key difference between our definitions for the intensity function is that the wolfram definition (the one that you linked) doesn't consider the filtration whereas the one from Wiki does. Do you know whether the authors' claim holds true using both definitions? 

My guess is that if they used a similar definition to the Wikipedia one, the stationarity assumption becomes a necessity for the claim to hold true? However, I am not sure.

Comment: @GerryT. : The definition of the intensity function makes sense for point processes over $\mathbb R$ but not immediately for point processes over $\mathbb R^2$.